# add zero to number in wicket

Tags: wicket-1.5

I have some problem with format number in Wicket. In textfiled with can only put five digit number-(xxxxx) if I put number less than five digit like 10  it can by automatically change format like 00010 with zero .How can I do it?. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String leadingZeros(int value, int returnSize){
    int size = (int) Math.log10(value)+1;
    if (size > returnSize){
        return String.valueOf(value).substring(size-returnSize);
    }
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=returnSize; i>size;i--){
        string.append("0");
    }
    string.append(value);
   return string.toString();
}
```

Example:

```
 System.out.println(leadingZeros(123,5));
 --> 00123

 System.out.println(leadingZeros(123456789,5));
 --> 56789
```